# Qt a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: qt, function

I have a function which calls emitResult after loading data from file.

```
bool IpResolver::ResolvedInfo::load(QTextStream &in)
{
ResolvedInfo rf;
while (!in.atEnd())
{
    QString line = in.readLine();
    QStringList list = line.split(' ');
    list[0] = rf.country;
    list[1] = rf.ip;
    if (rf.ip.isEmpty() == false)
    {
        emitResult(rf);
    }
}
}
```

So here is declaration of emitResult:

```
private:
    void emitResult(const ResolvedInfo &data);
```

And it gives me this error:
a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object
No idea what should I do.

Comment: Could you provide us with information about header declaration of `load()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`emitResult` is a non-static member function of `IpResolver`, I presume. Yet you're calling it without any instance, from a subclass `IpResolver::ResolvedInfo`. Remember that just because the `ResolvedInfo` is a subclass, doesn't make it special in any other way. Specifically, if it doesn't hold a reference to the instance of the parent class, it won't work the way you expect it to.

There are two general ways to fix your issue:

You can pass a reference to `IpResolver` to the `ResolvedInfo` constructor, and retain the reference in the `ResolvedInfo` instance:

```
class IpResolver {
  class ResolvedInfo {
    IpResolver & q;
  public:
    ResolvedInfo(IpResolver & q) : q(q) { ... }
    static bool load(QTextStream &in) {
      ResolvedInfo rf;
      while (!in.atEnd())
      {
        QString line = in.readLine();
        QStringList list = line.split(' ');
        list[0] = rf.country;
        list[1] = rf.ip;
        if (!rf.ip.isEmpty())
          q.emitResult(rf);
      }
    }
  };
  void emitResult(const ResolvedInfo &);
  ...
};
```

Or you can make the `emitResult` a static method:

```
class IpResolver {
  ...
  static void emitResult(const ResolvedInfo &);
};
```